# How to center JavaFX applet title?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, applet, javafx-8

Relevant code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("MousAbility");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image]

So "MousAbility" needs to be displayed on the centre of the title-bar (instead of on the left side like it is on the image).

Comment: In Windows, the title of every window is starting on the left side.. I don't know any functionality to change this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. You can undecorate the stage so the default controls are removed. Then you can add your custom controls to the top positions: Read [here](https://arnaudnouard.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/undecorator-add-a-better-look-to-your-javafx-stages-part-i/) for more information